# how to disable touch screen event while video is playing in android

Tags: android, events, youtube-api, touchscreen, disabled-control

I am developing kids app in which I have shown youtube videos thumbnails in RecyclerView. On the Click of any listed video thumbnail the video is played in full screen( using YouTube API to fetch the thumbnails and play video in Youtube intent). I am succeed i doing all so. The problem is that i want to disable the touch screen event while the video is playing. Every kind of help is appreciated. Below is my code:
mainactivity.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:weightSum="2"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.example.pc.fkidshell.Main4Activity">

    <include layout="@layout/toolbar"
        android:id="@+id/my_thirdtoolbar"/>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/VideoList"
        android:layout_below="@+id/my_thirdtoolbar"
        android:paddingTop="20dp"
        android:scrollbars="vertical">

    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

video_row.xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/thumbnailView"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

mainactivity.java:

```
public class Main4Activity extends AppCompatActivity implements YouTubeThumbnailView.OnInitializedListener, YouTubeThumbnailLoader.OnThumbnailLoadedListener{
    Toolbar third_toolbar;
    YouTubeThumbnailView thumbnailView;
    YouTubeThumbnailLoader thumbnailLoader;
    RecyclerView VideoList;
    RecyclerView.Adapter adapter;
    List<Drawable> thumbnailViews;
    List<String> VideoId;
    String videoid;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main4);
        third_toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.my_thirdtoolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(third_toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle(R.string.sectitle);
        getSupportActionBar().setIcon(R.drawable.tblogo);

        thumbnailViews = new ArrayList<>();
        VideoList = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.VideoList);
        RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager=new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        VideoList.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        adapter=new VideoListAdapter();
        VideoList.setAdapter(adapter);
        VideoId = new ArrayList<>();
        thumbnailView = new YouTubeThumbnailView(this);
        thumbnailView.initialize("API Key", this);

    }

    @Override
    public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubeThumbnailView youTubeThumbnailView, YouTubeThumbnailLoader youTubeThumbnailLoader) {
        thumbnailLoader = youTubeThumbnailLoader;
        youTubeThumbnailLoader.setOnThumbnailLoadedListener(Main4Activity.this);
        thumbnailLoader.setPlaylist("PLXRActLQ03oY_6AQb-5EMuKFYQA_fDE40");
    }

    @Override
    public void onInitializationFailure(YouTubeThumbnailView youTubeThumbnailView, YouTubeInitializationResult youTubeInitializationResult) {

    }

    public void add() {
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        if (thumbnailLoader.hasNext())
            thumbnailLoader.next();
    }

    @Override
    public void onThumbnailLoaded(YouTubeThumbnailView youTubeThumbnailView, String s) {
        thumbnailViews.add(youTubeThumbnailView.getDrawable());
        VideoId.add(s);
        add();
    }

    @Override
    public void onThumbnailError(YouTubeThumbnailView youTubeThumbnailView, YouTubeThumbnailLoader.ErrorReason errorReason) {

    }

    public class VideoListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<VideoListAdapter.MyView>{
        public class MyView extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
            ImageView imageView;
            public MyView(View itemView) {
                super(itemView);
                imageView= (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.thumbnailView);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public VideoListAdapter.MyView onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.video_row, parent, false);
            return new MyView(itemView);
        }

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(VideoListAdapter.MyView holder, final int position) {
            holder.imageView.setImageDrawable(thumbnailViews.get(position));
            holder.imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v)
                {
                    videoid=VideoId.get(position);

                    Intent intent=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://www.youtube.com/watch?v="+videoid+"&index="+position+"&list=PLXRActLQ03oY_6AQb-5EMuKFYQA_fDE40"));
                    intent.putExtra("force_fullscreen",true);
                    startActivity(intent);

                }
            });
        }

        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            return thumbnailViews.size();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: please remove your API key

Comment: Thanks! I forget.

Comment: I don't understand, why do you use Intent.ACTION_VIEW if you actually use Youtube API? You should use YouTubePlayerView.cueVideo(); or the others

Comment: I have use this because i want to play the videos in full screen.

Comment: Intent.ACTION_VIEW just simply retrieve any applications that support Intent.ACTION_VIEW with provided data, not play use Youtube player API

Comment: basically i am developing kids app which have shown me the list of kids videos which on click played in full screen with touch screen locked.

Answer (score 0):

My solution, you should make `YoutubePlayerActivity.java`

```
public class YoutubePlayerActivity extends YouTubeBaseActivity implements YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener,
        YouTubePlayer.PlaybackEventListener {

    public static final String KEY_VIDEO_ID = "videoId";
    private static final int RECOVERY_REQUEST = 1;
    private static final String API_KEY = "your API_KEY";

    private YouTubePlayerView youTubePlayerView;
    private View topLayer;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_youtube_player);

        youTubePlayerView = (YouTubePlayerView) findViewById(R.id.youtube_player);
        youTubePlayerView.initialize(API_KEY, this);

        topLayer = findViewById(R.id.top_layer);

        WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
        DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();
        wm.getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm);

        topLayer.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(dm.widthPixels - 1, dm.heightPixels - 1));
        topLayer.setClickable(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubePlayer youTubePlayer, boolean wasRestored) {
        if (!wasRestored) {
            youTubePlayer.setPlaybackEventListener(this);
            youTubePlayer.loadVideo(getIntent().getStringExtra(KEY_VIDEO_ID));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onInitializationFailure(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubeInitializationResult youTubeInitializationResult) {
        if (youTubeInitializationResult.isUserRecoverableError()) {
            youTubeInitializationResult.getErrorDialog(this, RECOVERY_REQUEST).show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == RECOVERY_REQUEST) {
            // Retry initialization if user performed a recovery action
            youTubePlayerView.initialize(API_KEY, this);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onPlaying() {
        topLayer.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPaused() {

    }

    @Override
    public void onStopped() {
        topLayer.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBuffering(boolean b) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onSeekTo(int i) {

    }
}
```

And create the layout, i named it `activity_youtube_player.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView
        android:id="@+id/youtube_player"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="false" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/top_layer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:clickable="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

You can start the `YoutubePlayerActivity` using

```
Intent openYoutubePlayerActivity = new Intent(context, YoutubePlayerActivity.class);
openYoutubePlayerActivity.putExtra(YoutubePlayerActivity.KEY_VIDEO_ID, videoId);
startActivity(openYoutubePlayerActivity);
```

So, what the code does? It will automatically play youtube video and it show transparent layer on top of `YouTubePlayerView` when the video starts. `android:clickable="true"` property on transparent layer will prevent any click directly to `YouTubePlayerView`. After the video stopped(either by error or video ended), it will remove the transparent layer.  You can also call `finish();` directly inside `onStopped()` method if you want.

Comment: I will surely try this and will respond shortly. Thanks

Comment: Sorry i just tested the code directly, this will not works, youtube player doesn't allow view overlay when the video is playing. It will automatically stops the video and show warning on logcat. You can search about YouTubePlayer.ErrorReason.UNAUTHORIZED_OVERLAY.

Comment: Maybe you can use the same technique but use WebView instead of YouTubePlayerView